# Integral over hemisphere not aligned with principle axis.

Tags: integration, change-of-variable

I'd like to integrate a function over a hemisphere (obtained from a sphere of radius $\delta$) whose flat side is normal to an arbitrary vector $\mathbf{n}$. I thought a change to spherical coordinates would be an appropriate way to solve this; however, the limits of integration are giving me a bit of trouble. I considered a modification of spherical coordinates so that the north pole is aligned with $\mathbf{n}$; however, this ended up being rather messy. If someone has a reference or a more elegant solution I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What (type of) function are you integrating?

Comment: I unfortunately cannot assume symmetry in the function I am integrating. It will likely be a spherical expansion which I will match the constants of to a physical system that may not have any imposed symmetry.